# I don't have build files for webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have installed webpack globally with `npm install webpack -g`.

I have also installed babel using `npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core`.

Any time I type webpack to get build files, I get this:

> C:\Sites\Learn-React>webpack
>
> Hash: 5d44ddfc6932f448e682
>
> Version: webpack 2.2.1
> Time: 71ms
>
> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel' in 'C:\Sites\Learn-React'
> BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
> You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel'.

Any idea on how this can be solved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do what the error message says:

> It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders. You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel'. Edit the `webpack.config.js` accordingly.

The rationale is that [automatic `-loader` module name extension has been removed](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed).

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, go to your `webpack.config.js` file and add `-loader` to babel. Look below:

```
  //INCORRECT

  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015']
          }
        }
    ]
  }


  //CORRECT

  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015']
          }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your module loaders and make sure to use the suffix '-loader'.

So for e.g:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 entry : './javascript/src/app.js',
 output: {
    path    : path.resolve(__dirname, 'javascript/dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
 },
 module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test   : /\.js$/,
            // Wrong
            // loader : 'babel',

            //Correct
            loader : 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
  }
};
```